# i m using sql plus in unix env so how can i write echo statement in spool file

Tags: unix, sqlplus

i getting the query out in spool file but if i want to write some echo statement before or after the  query result how is it possible 
e.g.

```
spool c:/test.txt
!echo "This is showing the details of employee"
select * from employee;
spool off
```

How can i get this line   "This is showing the details of employee" in spool file

Answer (score 0):

How about changing

```
!echo "This is showing the details of employee"
```

To

```
select "This is showing the details of employee" from dual;
```

IHTH